# Jquery and Updatepanel: binding jquery method at a common palce

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using multiple user control in my web page. Each of these usercontrol has $(document).ready() method. Because i am using an update panel, i am binding all the events again in end_request event. But I dont want to do that in all my usercontrols. Is is possible to do this at a common place(only once)?

thanks,
syd

Answer (score 0):

There are many interesting ways to do what you want. The simplest one is:

- make your ascx control's ClientIdMode to static
- in master page add call to init function which will handle init for all the ascx controls
  for example, if you have controls a1.ascx and b1.ascx having wrapped in `&ltdiv id="divA1">ascx markup ... </div>` and same is b1.ascx you can write something like:

```
var site = {
   init:function(){
    if($('#divA1').length > 0)
     {
         // bind events for the a1.ascx here
}
if($('#divB1').length >0)
{
    //bind events for a2
}

   }
};
$(function(){
    site.init();
});
```

--- update ----

if you are using asp.net 3.5 you can try following:

```
var site={
    ascx1_init:function(clientId){
        $('#'+clientId+'_Button1').live('click',function(){//button click code goes here});
    },
    ascx2_init:function(clientId){
        $('#'+clientId+'_Button1').live('click',function(){//button click code goes here});
    },
    ....
}
```

in each of your ascx, add following link at the end of page_load function:

`Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(),"_"+Me.ClientID,"site.ascx1_init('" & Me.ClientID & "');",True)`

I'm assuming you are using vb.net. So this way, you can access all your asp.net server controls in js and you can maintain single js without problem